# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, calendar

I'm running rails 3 on localhost and was getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

after following railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars, and putting both lines below into my application.html.erb file

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "application" %>
```

I actually solved this error by downloading jquery-ui.min.js file and putting it in my javascripts project folder, and replacing one of the lines, to the result below :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I also do not understand why i need to put my datepicker function inside my application.js :

```
$(function() {

  $('#start_date').datepicker();
  $('#end_date').datepicker();
})
```

and cannot put it on my users.js.coffee file with just the lines :

```
$('#start_date').datepicker();
$('#end_date').datepicker();
```

Anyone can explain why adding the js file locally solved this error, and why i cannot put my datepicker into my local coffee file, or if i can, can you please tell me how?

Thank you

Comment: +1 for explaining how to fix the "has no method 'datepicker'" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a coffescript expert, but I think you have to do this.

```
jQuery ->
  ### your code here ###
```

Comment: This solves my problem of putting context-specific scripts in application.js. Let us see if anyone can explain the first part of the question in two days. If not, i shall accept your answer

Comment: I would imagine that coffeescript is wondering where the variable datepicker came from.  But again, I don't use coffeescript.  I'd like to but it's not an option right now.